# Find all Local Documents in PouchDb database

Tags: pouchdb

PouchDb (& CouchDb) include the ability to store `Local Documents`. [1]

These aren't versioned or synced to remote instances.

CouchDb includes the `GET /{db}/_local_docs` API call, which will return the IDs of all local documents. [2]

PouchDb doesn't support this.

Is there another way of getting the IDs of local documents in PouchDb?

- [1]. https://pouchdb.com/guides/local-documents.html
- [2]. https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/local.html#db-local-docs

Comment: I've never seen it, I can't see a reason to do so, but you do. Perhaps wire up your own facility? For example have `_local/master` with an array member that contains all local document metadata and provide get/put/remove functions for local documents that keep `_local/master` up to date.

Comment: Thanks @RamblinRose - your solution worked well, and was better than the workaround we'd implemented.

Comment: Great, glad to have helped.  There are other, more subtle means - say using [transform-pouch](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/transform-pouch) or using the [changes](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) feed; but I think a deliberate approach is good enough.